# convertEntities() used before it is defined

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have an error generated from thickbox loading on every page including the admin area.  This is being printed into the html

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<![CDATA[ */ var thickboxL10n = {
next: "Next &gt;", prev: "&lt; Prev",image: 
"Image",  of: "of", close: "Close", 
noiframes: "This feature requires inline frames. You have iframes disabled or your browser does not support them." }; 
try{convertEntities(thickboxL10n);}catch(e){}; /* ]]> */ </script>
```

I would not really care but it is breaking firefox which sucks when the project is mid-development.  The problem is here:

> convertEntities is not defined
>
> Line 55
>   try{convertEntities(thickboxL10n);}catch(e){};

I tried to just stop it with a function

```
 function conditional_thickbox() {
  global $post;
  if (is_singular() &&
    strpos($post->post_content,'class="thickbox"') !== false) {
      wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
      wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
  }
}
add_action('wp_print_styles','conditional_thickbox');
```

That works well but it removes from everywhere and I realized this is a dependency for Wordpress image upload functionality.

I think I found the fix here :

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/16227/convertEntities-Firebug-Fix.diff

Which requires me hacking the core, any ideas on the best way to fix this ?

Comment: Don't see that problem with Firebug myself, what other firefox addons are you running and/or plugins in WordPress? Tried with plugins disabled or with firefox addons disabled(minus firebug of course)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `convertEntities` function was defined in `utils.js`, but if you use script concatenation this file would be included *after* it is needed. Because it was in a try-catch clause, the error was not (always) noticed.

The solution is to include the `convertEntities` function before this code is loaded. In WordPress 3.1 this is now included in [`l10n.js`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/js/l10n.js), [which you cannot disable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/what-does-l10n-js-do-in-wordpress-3-1-and-how-do-i-remove-it). A quick and dirty solution would be to copy this code and write it at the top of each page, so you are sure it is available.